# Commenting System - Showing posted comment without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, comments

working on a commenting system using PHP.

Everything works, the insert, the validation and also the ajax call.

Currently i am doing a .load() on the container that holds the page content.

However, this causes issues when trying to post comments again. The javascript doesnt work, some of the javascript functions linked with the comments also dont work and little things like that.

How should i be dealing with comments, every time a user posts one.

Like on facebook for example, you post a comment and the new one is just placed underneath the last.

The only thing i can think of i using .append() and appending the new comment to the list.

In my PHP page i could set a JSON return of the username, the comment, the users profile picture etc and then append all of that data back?

Otherwise is there a better method of simply 're-loading' the div container after the success ajax call?

Thanks, what i have works... but i want to be learning things the CORRECT way.

Craig.

Comment: Is the javascript you're trying to run loaded by `.load()`? If so the javascript pulled in by your script are not binded to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.ajax to load new comments and use .append() or prepend() to insert the new comments in the container. If you wrap the call in a function you can call the function over and over (for instance every 2 seconds) to check for new comments.

If I remember correctly .load() will only execute when the element is ready after browser refresh.

What things are not working? Remember that events and data must be bound after succesful AJAX call. Meaning if you bound events to links when the page loaded they are obviously still in effect. But if you insert a link later on it does not have any events.

What I would normally do is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: { 'parameters': 'yada yada' },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
        $('.links').unbind().click(function() { alert('hello!'); });
    }
});
```

The reason for the .unbind() is that you will otherwise bind several events on the existing links - and you don't want that ;-)